# Nivo Slider transitions not rendering correctly and increase in web page length

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I am developing an application in Rails 3.2 and trying to add a Nivo Slider to the front page. After it loads, the transitions look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxGow.png). Other transitions have similar distortions.

When the first transition occurs, the length of the page increases by thousands of pixels. I've determined that it is the #slider div that is increasing in size. This resets occasionally, but then I see it redraw the thousands of pixels down again.

The div containing the Nivo Slider:

```
<div id="content">
<link href="/assets/nivo-slider-themes/default/default.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
  <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="assets/index_slider_1.jpg">
    <img src="assets/index_slider_2.jpg">
    <img src="assets/index_slider_3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the default packaged CSS files that come with Nivo Slider 3.1.

[JSFiddle containing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/KAdfV/)

What is causing the transition corruption, and the increase in page length due to the slider div's length increasing?

Comment: We need some code. Ideally, a jsfiddle reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS file you are using from Nivo is causing the bug. I grabbed a stylesheet from one of the Nivo examples and updated the jsfiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/ppDhT/

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='nivoslider-css'  href='http://nivo.dev7studios.com/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider/scripts/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css?ver=3.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Cymen.  A bug report should be submitted to the developers.

Comment: @Steve is it a problem with a current package? I'm not very familiar with Nivo slider so I didn't know if it was a mistake from them or by those using it (accidentally using the wrong CSS). I would be happy to submit a bug but if you want to go for it.

Comment: Yeah, I let them know Cymen.